# Where is the ifcfg file of a (Host-only) virtual network adapter on CentOS?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

I'm using a CentOS virtual machine, i have already assigned two network adapters using the VMware Workstation but the Virtual Network Editor lets you change only the Subnet IP, the Subnet Mask and the MAC.

However, i also need to change the `IPADDR`, the `BROADCAST`, the `DHCP_HOSTNAME`, the `ON_BOOT` and the `DEVICE` variables on each network adapter.

I don't see any `ifcfg` file relevant to those two network adapters inside `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`. And i don't see those network adapters using the Network Administration Tool (system-config-network).

What is the most appropriate way to change those variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface configuration file under CentOS are named `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<ifname>` where `<ifname>` is the interface name. For interface `eth0`, the file will be named `ifcfg-eth0`.

In case someone assign an extra network card or change the configuration of an already existing then make sure to restart the network with `service network restart` in terminal.

Comment: then how do you explain that when i look into the network-scripts there is only one ifcfg file, the default "ifcfg-lo" and when i hit ifconfig -a in terminal i get both eth1 and eth2 as i expected?

Comment: Is it possible Cent was installed before you presented the network adapters to the virtual machine?  In any case, add the files with the proper settings, restart networking, and you should be off to the races.

Comment: correct! a service network restart was needed! thank you!